# Template app doesn't compile in Intellij Idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, aapt

I want to use Intellij Idea instead of Eclipse, but I can't even build a Hello World app.

When I try to build the project errors like this:

> [Hello World] /home/martin/workspace/Hello World/res/layout/main.xml:2: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'orientation' in package 'android'

I googled the error message and I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683488/aapt-tool-chokes-on-a-brand-new-android-project), but I'm still clueless. I guess I just have to edit a command in the IDE, but I have no idea how could I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the android dependencies to your module.  It should look something like this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it builds now. I also had to delete annotations.jar.